# Implementing an asynchronous call to a long running process MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, viewmodel

I have a large data set that holds up my UI so I thought I would create a background call to fill my local repository and display my other controls in the UI right away and load the results of the async call when I get a response.

I found a helpful tutorial but I am still having to wait until all my results are loaded before I see any controls.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

CODE UPDATED

I have created a folder called Services and created FacilitiesService.cs in that folder, see below:

```
public class FacilitiesService
{
    internal async Task<List<Facility>> GetFacilitiesBySourceDbAsync(string sourceDb)
    {
        var fac = new Facility();

        var con = Connect(); // Omitted

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: GetFacilityBySourceDb " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            OracleDataReader reader = null;
            // Requestor
            var cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT FACILITY, FACILITY_ID FROM MyTable where (source_db = '" + sourceDb + "')", con);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fac.Add(new Facility()
                {
                    FacilityName = reader["FACILITY"].ToString(),
                    FacilityId = reader["FACILITY_ID"].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        return fac;
    }
}
```

Then in my HomeController.cs I have the following:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public async Task<List<Facility>> FacilitiesAsync()
    {
        ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
        var service = new FacilitiesService();

        this._facilities = new List<Facility>();

        var facilities = await service.GetFacilitiesBySourceDbAsync("TEST");

        foreach (var item in facilities)
        {
            Facility fac = new Facility()
            {
                FacilityName = item.FacilityName,
                FacilityId = item.FacilityId
            };

            _facilities.Add(fac);
        }

        return _facilities;
    }
}
```

This is my Facility (model) class:

```
public class Facility : List<Facility>
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Facility")]
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public string FacilityId { get; set; }

    public Facility()
    {
        // Default Constructor
    }

    public Facility(string facilityName, string facilityId)
    {
        this.FacilityName = facilityName;
        this.FacilityId = facilityId;
    }
}
```

I am using an Ajax call to kick off the FacilitiesAsync method in the code behind from a function call in the About.cshtml page when the user tabs off the tetbox/input control with an id of "tags", I could switch this to something else later but I get the data back when I step through the code-behind and I see both the beforeSend and complete functions fire an alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
    // Neeed data from function call to populate this list
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    $("#tags").focusout(function () {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert("Testing");
            },
            url: "FacilitiesAsync",
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
     </div>
}
```

This works GREAT!  However, I want to take the data from the call made to the code-behind to populate the array availableTags and I'm not sure how to do that.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with the implementations, and one problem with the approach.

First, the `GetFacilitiesBySourceDbAsync` does not contain an `await`. The compiler will issue a warning in this situation, informing you that it's not really an asynchronous method when you do that; it will run synchronously. That's an important warning. If you want asynchronous code, you'll need to make it asynchronous all the way. This means using the asynchronous database methods (`ExecuteReaderAsync`, etc).

Secondly, the `Task.WhenAll` call in `Index` is meaningless (since you only pass it a single task). Also, since `Index` is synchronous but calls an asynchronous method, the code not shown is probably calling `Result`, which is a no-no on ASP.NET. As I explain on my blog, [this will actually deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) once your `async` code is actually asynchronous.

But even if you fix these, it won't do what you want. There's a problem with the approach, and that is that [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) (this is also a link to my blog). ASP.NET MVC understands asynchronous methods and will not complete the request until the `async` action method completes. You'll need to use something like AJAX to get the web page to do what you want.

Comment: I have completely changed the approach.  Please have a look and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This is now a JavaScript question instead of an `async` ASP.NET MVC question; you might want to ask a new more targeted question. As a general answer, I suggest you use promises.