# Assign data from ajax call to array / jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have data that is being returned from an ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       var result = null;
       $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("Testing");
        },
        url: "FacilitiesAsync",
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
     </div>
}
```

I would like to take this data, assigned to the result variable, and place this data in an jquery auto-complete input control.  My original post is below so you can see how I got the data.  I am getting back a List<> of type Facility, which is my custom class.  That data is an array of key value pairs.

[Implementing an asynchronous call to a long running process MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969374/implementing-an-asynchronous-call-to-a-long-running-process-mvc4)

Comment: What kind of data are you receiving in your ajax call?

Comment: I get this in the alert: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Facility]

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say you now know a major portion of your issue. You are returning a List<> to the client, but javascript doesn't support the data structures of what looks to me like C#. What you want to do is convert your list to json, so that you can traverse it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do now DeepThought.  Just figured out that is what I will have to do.  My local variable _facilities can be iterated through and I can get to the values like so: _facilities[0].FacilityName, for example.  I will update the code above.  I still need to figure out how to put that data as the source for the array which is what autocomplete uses for the input control.

Comment: I'm not overly knowledgable in C#, but a quick look at your code leaves me a bit confused on what you are actually doing. It looks to me in your code like you create a list of Facilities that you return then attempt to transcribe into another list of Facilities. Unless I'm missing something why not use the list you return instead of doubling your work? Also there should be a function in C# to convert your list to json, so I'd suggest looking into that

Comment: Yea, I am converting the list into JSON now.  My List is of type Facility.  So I have created a list of facilities, but I am not doing it twice.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not overly knowledgeable about C#, but you seem to be creating a Collection of Facility objects in your Facility service. Which is then returned to your home controller, iterated over in order to copy to a List<Facility> data structure. So I'm just reading it as you are copying a collection to a formal list when you should be able to return the List<Facility> data structure in the first place, thus double the work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$.ajax('@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {httproute = "", controller = "Company"})').done(function(data) {
                $("#yourinput").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                        response($.grep(data, function(value) {
                            value = value.label || value.value || value;
                            return matcher.test(value) || matcher.test(normalize(value));
                        }));
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is the way I just get it to work a week ago or so, so I think it should be similar for you

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I am  looking for.